# How to inject a many-to-many relationship into third-party models?

Tags: python, django, code-injection, django-orm

I want to insert a many-to-many relationship into some models, without having to completely rewrite the models.

For example, consider the django `User` model and a model `Foo` from a third-party module I've installed.

If I 'owned' Foo I could just do:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToMany(User)
```

Then, if I wanted to add a `Foo` to user, or vice versa I could do:

```
my_user.foo_set.add(my_foo)
my_foo.users.add(my_user)
```

But I don't 'own' either code, and I want to inject this relationship, so I can do the above.

Now, if I wanted I could even do a through relationship through a model I made and and put that on either side, but that still requires altering the models.

Now, behind the scenes it looks like django many-to-many relationships are models (they definitely have tables), is it possible to make this code:

```
class FooUserRelationship(models.Model):
    foo = ForeignKey(Foo)
    user = ForeignKey(User)
```

Act just like a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: You should be able to define the many to many relationship from the model under your control. In your case subclass `User` add the relation with back reference and define `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in the settings.

Answer (score 1):

you can use proxy models. Here person is a 3rd party model and Myperson is a your model modifying extra attributes to the main models. for more details https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#proxy-models

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class MyPerson(Person):
    users = models.ManyToMany(User)
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Comment: Close. But not quite. I need the relationship visible on both concrete models. Have an up-vote because this is nifty.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way i can think of is to provide a middle class (or you could subclass which would provide the almost the same queries) with a onetoone to one side and then many to many

```
class FooUser(models.Model):
    user = OneToOneField(AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    foo = ManyToMany(Foo)   

my_user.foouser.foo_set.add(my_foo)
my_foo.foousers.add(my_user.foouser)
```

Now I admit that this isn't the cleanest way of doing things since it would involve a further SQL join when retrieving results, but it does keep in tact your link and provides a way to modify as you please.